# Item Array as Datasource for NgFor

Tags: arrays, angular, grid, datasource

Just want to ask if is it possible to  search an item in an array of objects and use it as datasource for my angular table? Can you share the syntax please?

Basically, i have an array of objects consisting of Id and its json file. Populate its data. Look for an item that matches the it, and use it as datasource in a ngfor grid.

I have the following code, but it returns compilation error.

Thanks

ts file

```
jsonData: Array<{ id: string, json: object }> = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
let json= [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Col1": "val11",
    "Col2": "val12
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Col1": "val21",
    "Col2": "val22
  }
]

this.jsonData.push({ id: "100", json: json });
}
```

html file

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of this.jsonData.find(e => e.id === "101").json;let i=row.Id">
        row.Col1 //etc..
</ng-container>
```

Comment: is it possible for you to share your code on stackblitz?

Comment: @RishabVaigankar, sorry but still newbie on angular and still no knowledge of how to post in stackblitz

Comment: Hi, are you planning to use angular material along with it to display your data ?

Comment: Hi millenion, yes, im planning to use mat-grid-list..

Comment: @SeigfredMondez Did you try creating a pipe in Angular? I've created an implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2gr7jg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that you can follow. Let me know it works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have used a different approach check if this helps you out . I am  filtering data from the constructer itself (ts file)

here is the code link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wn7vwb?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((res) => res.name == 'Helium');
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was also thinking of this route, but was thinking the other way thus eliminating some lines of code on the ts file. Maybe ill go this way now. Just a quick question, what if the "helium" value is from the html file going to ts file? can you share the syntax please.

Comment: sorry did not get your question @SeigfredMondez

Comment: constructor() {
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((res) => res.name == 'Helium');
  }

I mean, how can you pass a parameter or variable to your this.dataSource.filter((res) => res.name == valuefromhtml);?

Comment: you can write a function in html side like <button (click)="filterSource("Helium")">
and inside ts file 
 filterSource(val) {
   this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((res) => res.name ==val);
  }

can you try this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did what you said and its already working. Many thanks Rishab